# To change a scroll bar Styling

Tags: html, css

Can we change a scroll bar styling, Instead of default scroll bar, I want to place a image on it.

Comment: I provided a detailed answer to similar SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14150577/1085891 You might find it helpful if you are still interested in styling scroll bars and/or want cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

IE allow change color of some scrollbar elements. But other browsers - NO.
The only solution is use custom JS to implement this. But this is always more ugly and non-useful instead of native controls.

Take a look at: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Comment: Using the above script i customized my scroll bar.

Comment: And using the above script, no problem with ie7 and ie6 its works in IE browsers.

Comment: Webkit also allows styling of scrollbars — http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you - [flexScroll](http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar)

This does not place an image over the scrollbar, it creates a virtual scrollbar. I don't know if it is possible to gain control over scrollbar using html/js.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an image for the scroll-bars, but you can change the colour of them.  See [this page](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/colored_custom_scrollbar_tutorial.php3) for information on how to do it.

Be aware that the scrollbar properties are not valid CSS, and not all browsers will obey the style of the scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a link for the similar effect,hope it helps..

```
[http://www.hiddenpixels.com/javascript/custom-javascript-scrollbar/][1]
```