# CSS customized scroll bar in div

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

How can I customize a scroll bar via CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) for one `div` and not the whole page?

Comment: Apply `overflow:auto;` just to that `<div>`. Any more background details?

Comment: I did that , but i need custom scrollbar , uhm.. design of scrollbar

Comment: Custom color? That's only supported in IE, and not in other modern browsers. This cannot be achieved using pure CSS.

Comment: Simplest JS solution (CSS has **no** cross-browser support) - http://yaireo.github.io/fakescroll/

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357203/custom-scrollbars/32424642#32424642

Comment: If you're using ReactJS you can use [react-custom-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-scroll), it works great on all browsers, and allows changing the scroll style for specific areas.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Answer (score 714, accepted):

I thought it would be helpful to consolidate the latest information on scroll bars, CSS, and browser compatibility.

## Scroll Bar CSS Support

Currently, there exists no cross-browser scroll bar CSS styling definitions. [The W3C article](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/scrollbars.en.html) I mention at the end has the following statement and was recently updated (10 Oct 2014):

> Some browsers (IE, Konqueror) support the non-standard properties 'scrollbar-shadow-color', 'scrollbar-track-color' and others. **These properties are illegal: they are neither defined in any CSS specification nor are they marked as proprietary (by prefixing them with "-vendor-")**

### Microsoft

As others have mentioned, Microsoft supports scroll bar styling, but only for IE8 and above.

Example:

```css
.TA {
    scrollbar-3dlight-color:gold;
    scrollbar-arrow-color:blue;
    scrollbar-base-color:;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color:blue;
    scrollbar-face-color:;
    scrollbar-highlight-color:;
    scrollbar-shadow-color:
}
```

### Chrome & Safari (WebKit)

Similarly, WebKit now has its own version:

- Styling scrollbars: https://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/
- [Demo of all WebKit scroll bar styling](https://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/overflow-scrollbar-combinations.html)
- From [Custom scrollbars in WebKit](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/), relevant CSS:

  ```css
   /* pseudo elements */
   ::-webkit-scrollbar              {  }
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-button       {  }
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-track        {  }
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {  }
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        {  }
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       {  }
   ::-webkit-resizer                {  }

   /* pseudo class selectors */
   :horizontal
   :vertical
   :decrement
   :increment
   :start
   :end 
   :double-button
   :single-button
   :no-button
   :corner-present
   :window-inactive
  ```

### Firefox (Gecko)

As of version 64 Firefox supports scrollbar styling through the properties `scrollbar-color` (partially, [W3C draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1/#scrollbar-color)) and `scrollbar-width` ([W3C draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1/#scrollbar-width)). Some good information about the implementation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101063/6396604).

## Cross-browser Scroll Bar Styling

JavaScript libraries and plug-ins can provide a cross-browser solution. There are many options.

- [20 jQuery Scrollbar plugin with examples](http://www.bestjquery.com/2012/07/jquery-scrollbar-plugin-examples/) (July 24, 2012)

  - [NiceScroll : jQuery Scrolling plugin for desktop,mobile & touch devices](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-nicescroll/)
  - [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)
  - [Tiny Scrollbar – A lightweight jQuery plugin](http://www.bestjquery.com/?8OKI7cdR)
  - etc.
- [30+ JavaScript/Ajax Techniques for Sliders, Scrollers and Scrollbars](http://www.noupe.com/javascript/30-javascriptajax-techniques-for-sliders-scrollers-and-scrollbars.html) (May 07, 2008)
- [21 Useful Scrollbar CSS/JavaScript Styling Tutorials](http://ginva.com/2012/08/21-useful-scrollbar-css-javascript-styling-tutorials/) (August, 2012)
- [15+ Free and Premium jQuery Scrolling Plugins](http://designmodo.com/jquery-scrolling-plugins/) (August 26, 2012)

The list could go on. Your best bet is to search around, research, and test the available solutions. I am sure you will be able to find something that will fit your needs.

## Prevent Illegal Scroll Bar Styling

Just in case you want to prevent scroll bar styling that hasn't been properly prefixed with "-vendor", [this article over at W3C provides some basic instructions](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/scrollbars.en.html). Basically, you'll need to add the following CSS to a user style sheet associated with your browser. These definitions will override invalid scroll bar styling on any page you visit.

```css
body, html {
  scrollbar-face-color: ThreeDFace !important;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: ThreeDDarkShadow !important;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: ThreeDHighlight !important;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: ThreeDLightShadow !important;
  scrollbar-darkshadow-color: ThreeDDarkShadow !important;
  scrollbar-track-color: Scrollbar !important;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: ButtonText !important;
}
```

## Duplicate or Similar Questions / Source Not Linked Above

- [Changing the scrollbars' style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203107/changing-the-scrollbars-style)
- [CSS scrollbar style cross browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser)
- [How to create a custom scrollbar on a div (Facebook style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945547/how-to-create-a-custom-scrollbar-on-a-div)

**Note:** This answer contains information from various sources. If a source was used, then it is also linked in this answer.

Comment: The web has been around for over two decades, and there still isn't a standard way to style scrollbars. Twenty years of standards committees not noticing that people scroll things. There is no rate of slow, sarcastic clapping that would adequately express how that makes me feel. But a 20 year delay between the first and second clap would, I think, be fitting. For some perspective, I wasn't born yet when WWW came out, and I'm a computer engineer now. Way to go, W3C.

Comment: Experience: Tiny scrollbar requires inserting a lot of DIV into the document, which is inconvenient to use. Tiny Scroll is easier to implement.

Comment: Just to add my two cents: Gmail and Youtube have stylized scrollbar in Chrome, and native one in Explorer and Firefox. If those standards are good enough for them it's good enough for me too

Comment: @ParthianShot: “Twenty years of standards committees not noticing that people scroll things”. Maybe they did notice that people scroll things, and thought that if scrollbars looked the same on every website, it would be better, because then people can always recognise them and understand how they work.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Well, maybe, but that can be applied to anything. And CSS exists as a language precisely so that designers can choose to override defaults. The whole idea is that a bad UI designer can make any element unintuitive, but as soon as you assume the site designer is incompetent, what's the point in allowing page customization at all?

Comment: @ParthianShot: some things are important enough to insist on a consistent design. Some things aren’t.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Clearly, this isn't one of those things. Partly because it's in the area of the screen which the site designer should control entirely, anyway, so it poses no security risk, and partly because clearly- in practice- it's a non-issue. Plenty of sites implement their own hacks to make things that look and behave like scrollbars, and they work fine. Not only do they work fine, and look better, but people actually understand how to use them, which is the point. Unfortunately, because they're hacks, sometimes they won't play well with things like printing functionality.

Comment: This answer doesn't completely address his question, which was how to apply scrollbar styles to a specific *div*, rather than an entire page.

Comment: It's worth noting that Opera has since switched to WebKit too (and now its offshoot, Blink), so `-webkit` styles should work there also. And Safari still uses WebKit based tech, ala WebKit2. Now all you have to work against for a *legal* native solution are Firefox and IE/Edge.

Comment: CSS control of Scrollbars is finally being discussed by W3C and is at the draft stage: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1/

Answer (score 16):

Give this a try

Source : https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/

Simple Implementation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(

  function() { 

    $("html").niceScroll();

  }

);
</script>
```

It is a jQuery plugin scrollbar, so your scrollbars are controllable and look the same across the various OS's.

Comment: I'm sure it's probably customizable, but the demo on their page scrolls far too slow and the scrollbar is far too difficult to grab.

Comment: Like virtually all jQuery plugins -- *[shudders]* -- this is _awfully_ slow compared to native, threaded, GPU accelerated scroll implementations. _Completely_ unsuitable for serious applications, and a hindrance to good UX. I'd recommend you avoid this, unless it's for a toy website.

Comment: I hate it when people call something pure javascript then BAM! a jquery plugin.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using nicescroll, since it disables browser functionality. Scrolling with middle click doesn't work with nicescroll.

Comment: love this niceScroll, it doesn't add wrapper div around element which means it doesn't break the html structure

Answer (score 11):

Please check this link:
[CSS Scroll Bars](https://codepen.io/GhostRider/pen/GHaFw)

Example with working demo

```css
    #style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-track
    {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }
    
    #style-1::-webkit-scrollbar
    {
        width: 12px;
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }
    
    #style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
    {
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        background-color: #555;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the demo.  I first ran it with Firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit, Windows 7 Pro/64) and ***all of its scroll bars were identical.***  Then ran with Chrome Version 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit) and they were all different.  So (perhaps unintentionally) you have demonstrated the limitations of the `-webkit-` approach.

Comment: it's not cross-browseer

Comment: This answer, I believe, properly fulfills the question being asked in regards to not overriding the browsers main scrollbars by targeting the specific element desired.

Answer (score 10):

Custom scroll bars aren't possible with CSS, you'll need some JavaScript magic.

Some browsers support non-spec CSS rules, such as `::-webkit-scrollbar` in Webkit but is not ideal since it'll only work in Webkit. IE had something like that too, but I don't think they support it anymore.

Comment: obsolete answer

Comment: @T.Todua What is obsolete about this answer?

Answer (score 8):

Like many people, I was looking for something that was:

- Consistently styled and functional across most modern browsers
- Not some ridiculous 3000-line bloated jQuery extension cr*p

...But alas - nothing!

Well if a job's worth doing... I was able to get something up and running in about 30 mins.
Disclaimer: there's quite a few known (and probably a few as yet unknown) problems with it, but it makes me wonder what on Earth the other 2920 lines of JS are there for in many offerings!

```js
(window => {

  let initCoords;

  const coords_update = e => {
    if (initCoords) {
      const elem = initCoords.bar.closest('.scrollr');
      const eSuffix = initCoords.axis.toUpperCase();
      const sSuffix = initCoords.axis == 'x' ? 'Left' : 'Top';
      const dSuffix = initCoords.axis == 'x' ? 'Width' : 'Height';
      const max = elem['scroll' + dSuffix] - elem['client' + dSuffix];
      const room = elem['client' + dSuffix] - initCoords.bar['client' + dSuffix];
      const delta = e['page' + eSuffix] - initCoords.abs;
      const abs = initCoords.p0 + delta;
      elem['scroll' + sSuffix] = max * abs / room;
    }
  };

  const scrollr_resize = elem => {
    const xBar = elem.querySelector('.track.x .bar');
    const yBar = elem.querySelector('.track.y .bar');
    const xRel = elem.clientWidth / elem.scrollWidth;
    const yRel = elem.clientHeight / elem.scrollHeight;
    xBar.style.width = (100 * xRel).toFixed(2) + '%';
    yBar.style.height = (100 * yRel).toFixed(2) + '%';
  };

  const scrollr_init = elem => {
    const xTrack = document.createElement('span');
    const yTrack = document.createElement('span');
    const xBar = document.createElement('span');
    const yBar = document.createElement('span');
    xTrack.className = 'track x';
    yTrack.className = 'track y';
    xBar.className = 'bar';
    yBar.className = 'bar';
    xTrack.appendChild(xBar);
    yTrack.appendChild(yBar);
    elem.appendChild(xTrack);
    elem.appendChild(yTrack);
    elem.addEventListener('wheel', scrollr_OnWheel);
    elem.addEventListener('scroll', scrollr_OnScroll);
    xTrack.addEventListener('wheel', xTrack_OnWheel);
    xTrack.addEventListener('click', xTrack_OnClick);
    xTrack.addEventListener('mouseover', () => xTrack.classList.add('active'));
    xTrack.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
      if (!initCoords) xTrack.classList.remove('active');
    });
    yTrack.addEventListener('click', yTrack_OnClick);
    yTrack.addEventListener('mouseover', () => yTrack.classList.add('active'));
    yTrack.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
      if (!initCoords) yTrack.classList.remove('active');
    });
    xBar.addEventListener('click', bar_OnClick);
    xBar.addEventListener('mousedown', xBar_OnMouseDown);
    yBar.addEventListener('click', bar_OnClick);
    yBar.addEventListener('mousedown', yBar_OnMouseDown);

    scrollr_resize(elem);
  };

  window.addEventListener('load', e => {
    const scrollrz = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.scrollr'));
    scrollrz.forEach(scrollr_init);
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
    const scrollrz = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.scrollr'));
    scrollrz.forEach(scrollr_resize);
  });

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', coords_update);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    initCoords = null;
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.track.active'))
      .forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove('active'));
  });

  function xBar_OnMouseDown(e) {
    const p0 = this.offsetLeft;
    initCoords = {
      axis: 'x',
      abs: e.pageX,
      bar: this,
      p0
    };
  }

  function yBar_OnMouseDown(e) {
    const p0 = this.offsetTop;
    initCoords = {
      axis: 'y',
      abs: e.pageY,
      bar: this,
      p0
    };
  }

  function bar_OnClick(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  function xTrack_OnClick(e) {
    const elem = this.closest('.scrollr');
    const xBar = this.querySelector('.bar');
    let unit = elem.clientWidth - 30;
    if (e.offsetX <= xBar.offsetLeft) unit *= -1;
    elem.scrollLeft += unit;
  }

  function yTrack_OnClick(e) {
    const elem = this.closest('.scrollr');
    const yBar = this.querySelector('.bar');
    let unit = elem.clientHeight - 30;
    if (e.offsetY <= yBar.offsetTop) unit *= -1;
    elem.scrollTop += unit;
  }

  function xTrack_OnWheel(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const elem = this.closest('.scrollr');
    const left0 = elem.scrollLeft;
    const delta = e.deltaY !== 0 ? e.deltaY : e.deltaX;
    elem.scrollLeft += delta;
    const moved = left0 !== elem.scrollLeft;
    if (moved) e.preventDefault();
  }

  function scrollr_OnWheel(e) {
    const left0 = this.scrollLeft;
    const top0 = this.scrollTop;
    this.scrollLeft += e.deltaX;
    this.scrollTop += e.deltaY;
    const moved = left0 !== this.scrollLeft || top0 !== this.scrollTop;
    if (moved) e.preventDefault();
  }

  function scrollr_OnScroll(e) {
    const xTrack = this.querySelector('.track.x');
    const yTrack = this.querySelector('.track.y');
    const xBar = xTrack.querySelector('.bar');
    const yBar = yTrack.querySelector('.bar');

    const xMax = this.scrollWidth - this.clientWidth;
    const yMax = this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight;
    const xFrac = this.scrollLeft / xMax;
    const yFrac = this.scrollTop / yMax;
    const xAbs = xFrac * (this.clientWidth - xBar.clientWidth);
    const yAbs = yFrac * (this.clientHeight - yBar.clientHeight);

    xTrack.style.left = this.scrollLeft + 'px';
    xTrack.style.bottom = -this.scrollTop + 'px';
    xBar.style.left = xAbs + 'px';

    yTrack.style.top = this.scrollTop + 'px';
    yTrack.style.right = -this.scrollLeft + 'px';
    yBar.style.top = yAbs + 'px';
  };

})(window);
```

```css
.scrollr {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.track {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  user-select: none;
}

.track.x {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}

.track.y {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: background-color .3s, opacity .3s, width .3s, height .3s, margin .3s;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .7;
}

.track.x .bar {
  min-width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px 0 2px 0;
}

.track.y .bar {
  min-height: 25px;
  width: 3px;
  margin: 0 2px 0 5px;
}

.track.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.track.active .bar {
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.track.x.active .bar {
  height: 10px;
}

.track.y.active .bar {
  width: 10px;
}


/* Custom client stuff */

.content {
  background: red;
}

.content p {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0;
}

.scrollr {
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollr content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc diam magna, molestie sit amet auctor nec, dictum quis mi. Duis pellentesque lacinia pretium. Donec pulvinar, risus sit amet dapibus mattis, eros urna bibendum elit, vel mollis sapien arcu
    vitae mi. Fusce vulputate vestibulum metus dapibus eleifend. Quisque ut dictum orci. Nunc bibendum, sapien ac condimentum placerat, arcu orci mollis nunc, vitae sollicitudin arcu nulla quis enim. Praesent non tellus vitae quam tempor maximus vel sed
    dolor. Donec id ante ultricies, iaculis sem ut, sollicitudin enim. Quisque id mauris est. Maecenas viverra urna vitae velit semper, vel ultricies augue feugiat. Pellentesque in libero porttitor, lacinia metus in, maximus nisi. Phasellus commodo ligula
    vel arcu iaculis hendrerit vitae vel diam. Sed sed lorem maximus, vestibulum leo ut, posuere libero. Donec arcu dui, euismod id aliquet sed, porttitor vitae elit.</p>
  <p>Sed aliquam eget justo sit amet dictum. Suspendisse potenti. In placerat orci quis vehicula vehicula. Proin tempor laoreet suscipit. Proin non nulla lacinia est ullamcorper maximus et a sem. Nulla at lacus rhoncus, malesuada ante in, imperdiet sem.
    Mauris convallis tristique metus in iaculis. Nulla laoreet ligula non interdum tincidunt. Morbi sed venenatis arcu, sed gravida est. Fusce malesuada ullamcorper lacus, in vulputate risus finibus non.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse sapien leo, auctor non ex vitae, volutpat laoreet tortor. Suspendisse sodales libero velit, sed pulvinar lectus feugiat vel. Sed erat eros, porttitor id enim nec, ornare hendrerit nibh. Phasellus at nisi lectus. Cras semper lobortis condimentum.
    Etiam nunc felis, vehicula vitae tincidunt pellentesque, pretium sit amet dui. Duis aliquet ultrices lacus eget efficitur. Ut imperdiet velit sed enim laoreet, sed semper libero hendrerit. Donec malesuada auctor sollicitudin.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc diam magna, molestie sit amet auctor nec, dictum quis mi. Duis pellentesque lacinia pretium. Donec pulvinar, risus sit amet dapibus mattis, eros urna bibendum elit, vel mollis sapien arcu
    vitae mi. Fusce vulputate vestibulum metus dapibus eleifend. Quisque ut dictum orci. Nunc bibendum, sapien ac condimentum placerat, arcu orci mollis nunc, vitae sollicitudin arcu nulla quis enim. Praesent non tellus vitae quam tempor maximus vel sed
    dolor. Donec id ante ultricies, iaculis sem ut, sollicitudin enim. Quisque id mauris est. Maecenas viverra urna vitae velit semper, vel ultricies augue feugiat. Pellentesque in libero porttitor, lacinia metus in, maximus nisi. Phasellus commodo ligula
    vel arcu iaculis hendrerit vitae vel diam. Sed sed lorem maximus, vestibulum leo ut, posuere libero. Donec arcu dui, euismod id aliquet sed, porttitor vitae elit.</p>
  <p>Sed aliquam eget justo sit amet dictum. Suspendisse potenti. In placerat orci quis vehicula vehicula. Proin tempor laoreet suscipit. Proin non nulla lacinia est ullamcorper maximus et a sem. Nulla at lacus rhoncus, malesuada ante in, imperdiet sem.
    Mauris convallis tristique metus in iaculis. Nulla laoreet ligula non interdum tincidunt. Morbi sed venenatis arcu, sed gravida est. Fusce malesuada ullamcorper lacus, in vulputate risus finibus non.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse sapien leo, auctor non ex vitae, volutpat laoreet tortor. Suspendisse sodales libero velit, sed pulvinar lectus feugiat vel. Sed erat eros, porttitor id enim nec, ornare hendrerit nibh. Phasellus at nisi lectus. Cras semper lobortis condimentum.
    Etiam nunc felis, vehicula vitae tincidunt pellentesque, pretium sit amet dui. Duis aliquet ultrices lacus eget efficitur. Ut imperdiet velit sed enim laoreet, sed semper libero hendrerit. Donec malesuada auctor sollicitudin.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc diam magna, molestie sit amet auctor nec, dictum quis mi. Duis pellentesque lacinia pretium. Donec pulvinar, risus sit amet dapibus mattis, eros urna bibendum elit, vel mollis sapien arcu
    vitae mi. Fusce vulputate vestibulum metus dapibus eleifend. Quisque ut dictum orci. Nunc bibendum, sapien ac condimentum placerat, arcu orci mollis nunc, vitae sollicitudin arcu nulla quis enim. Praesent non tellus vitae quam tempor maximus vel sed
    dolor. Donec id ante ultricies, iaculis sem ut, sollicitudin enim. Quisque id mauris est. Maecenas viverra urna vitae velit semper, vel ultricies augue feugiat. Pellentesque in libero porttitor, lacinia metus in, maximus nisi. Phasellus commodo ligula
    vel arcu iaculis hendrerit vitae vel diam. Sed sed lorem maximus, vestibulum leo ut, posuere libero. Donec arcu dui, euismod id aliquet sed, porttitor vitae elit.</p>
  <p>Sed aliquam eget justo sit amet dictum. Suspendisse potenti. In placerat orci quis vehicula vehicula. Proin tempor laoreet suscipit. Proin non nulla lacinia est ullamcorper maximus et a sem. Nulla at lacus rhoncus, malesuada ante in, imperdiet sem.
    Mauris convallis tristique metus in iaculis. Nulla laoreet ligula non interdum tincidunt. Morbi sed venenatis arcu, sed gravida est. Fusce malesuada ullamcorper lacus, in vulputate risus finibus non.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse sapien leo, auctor non ex vitae, volutpat laoreet tortor. Suspendisse sodales libero velit, sed pulvinar lectus feugiat vel. Sed erat eros, porttitor id enim nec, ornare hendrerit nibh. Phasellus at nisi lectus. Cras semper lobortis condimentum.
    Etiam nunc felis, vehicula vitae tincidunt pellentesque, pretium sit amet dui. Duis aliquet ultrices lacus eget efficitur. Ut imperdiet velit sed enim laoreet, sed semper libero hendrerit. Donec malesuada auctor sollicitudin.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc diam magna, molestie sit amet auctor nec, dictum quis mi. Duis pellentesque lacinia pretium. Donec pulvinar, risus sit amet dapibus mattis, eros urna bibendum elit, vel mollis sapien arcu
    vitae mi. Fusce vulputate vestibulum metus dapibus eleifend. Quisque ut dictum orci. Nunc bibendum, sapien ac condimentum placerat, arcu orci mollis nunc, vitae sollicitudin arcu nulla quis enim. Praesent non tellus vitae quam tempor maximus vel sed
    dolor. Donec id ante ultricies, iaculis sem ut, sollicitudin enim. Quisque id mauris est. Maecenas viverra urna vitae velit semper, vel ultricies augue feugiat. Pellentesque in libero porttitor, lacinia metus in, maximus nisi. Phasellus commodo ligula
    vel arcu iaculis hendrerit vitae vel diam. Sed sed lorem maximus, vestibulum leo ut, posuere libero. Donec arcu dui, euismod id aliquet sed, porttitor vitae elit.</p>
  <p>Sed aliquam eget justo sit amet dictum. Suspendisse potenti. In placerat orci quis vehicula vehicula. Proin tempor laoreet suscipit. Proin non nulla lacinia est ullamcorper maximus et a sem. Nulla at lacus rhoncus, malesuada ante in, imperdiet sem.
    Mauris convallis tristique metus in iaculis. Nulla laoreet ligula non interdum tincidunt. Morbi sed venenatis arcu, sed gravida est. Fusce malesuada ullamcorper lacus, in vulputate risus finibus non.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse sapien leo, auctor non ex vitae, volutpat laoreet tortor. Suspendisse sodales libero velit, sed pulvinar lectus feugiat vel. Sed erat eros, porttitor id enim nec, ornare hendrerit nibh. Phasellus at nisi lectus. Cras semper lobortis condimentum.
    Etiam nunc felis, vehicula vitae tincidunt pellentesque, pretium sit amet dui. Duis aliquet ultrices lacus eget efficitur. Ut imperdiet velit sed enim laoreet, sed semper libero hendrerit. Donec malesuada auctor sollicitudin.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc diam magna, molestie sit amet auctor nec, dictum quis mi. Duis pellentesque lacinia pretium. Donec pulvinar, risus sit amet dapibus mattis, eros urna bibendum elit, vel mollis sapien arcu
    vitae mi. Fusce vulputate vestibulum metus dapibus eleifend. Quisque ut dictum orci. Nunc bibendum, sapien ac condimentum placerat, arcu orci mollis nunc, vitae sollicitudin arcu nulla quis enim. Praesent non tellus vitae quam tempor maximus vel sed
    dolor. Donec id ante ultricies, iaculis sem ut, sollicitudin enim. Quisque id mauris est. Maecenas viverra urna vitae velit semper, vel ultricies augue feugiat. Pellentesque in libero porttitor, lacinia metus in, maximus nisi. Phasellus commodo ligula
    vel arcu iaculis hendrerit vitae vel diam. Sed sed lorem maximus, vestibulum leo ut, posuere libero. Donec arcu dui, euismod id aliquet sed, porttitor vitae elit.</p>
  <p>Sed aliquam eget justo sit amet dictum. Suspendisse potenti. In placerat orci quis vehicula vehicula. Proin tempor laoreet suscipit. Proin non nulla lacinia est ullamcorper maximus et a sem. Nulla at lacus rhoncus, malesuada ante in, imperdiet sem.
    Mauris convallis tristique metus in iaculis. Nulla laoreet ligula non interdum tincidunt. Morbi sed venenatis arcu, sed gravida est. Fusce malesuada ullamcorper lacus, in vulputate risus finibus non.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse sapien leo, auctor non ex vitae, volutpat laoreet tortor. Suspendisse sodales libero velit, sed pulvinar lectus feugiat vel. Sed erat eros, porttitor id enim nec, ornare hendrerit nibh. Phasellus at nisi lectus. Cras semper lobortis condimentum.
    Etiam nunc felis, vehicula vitae tincidunt pellentesque, pretium sit amet dui. Duis aliquet ultrices lacus eget efficitur. Ut imperdiet velit sed enim laoreet, sed semper libero hendrerit. Donec malesuada auctor sollicitudin.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc diam magna, molestie sit amet auctor nec, dictum quis mi. Duis pellentesque lacinia pretium. Donec pulvinar, risus sit amet dapibus mattis, eros urna bibendum elit, vel mollis sapien arcu
    vitae mi. Fusce vulputate vestibulum metus dapibus eleifend. Quisque ut dictum orci. Nunc bibendum, sapien ac condimentum placerat, arcu orci mollis nunc, vitae sollicitudin arcu nulla quis enim. Praesent non tellus vitae quam tempor maximus vel sed
    dolor. Donec id ante ultricies, iaculis sem ut, sollicitudin enim. Quisque id mauris est. Maecenas viverra urna vitae velit semper, vel ultricies augue feugiat. Pellentesque in libero porttitor, lacinia metus in, maximus nisi. Phasellus commodo ligula
    vel arcu iaculis hendrerit vitae vel diam. Sed sed lorem maximus, vestibulum leo ut, posuere libero. Donec arcu dui, euismod id aliquet sed, porttitor vitae elit.</p>
  <p>Sed aliquam eget justo sit amet dictum. Suspendisse potenti. In placerat orci quis vehicula vehicula. Proin tempor laoreet suscipit. Proin non nulla lacinia est ullamcorper maximus et a sem. Nulla at lacus rhoncus, malesuada ante in, imperdiet sem.
    Mauris convallis tristique metus in iaculis. Nulla laoreet ligula non interdum tincidunt. Morbi sed venenatis arcu, sed gravida est. Fusce malesuada ullamcorper lacus, in vulputate risus finibus non.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse sapien leo, auctor non ex vitae, volutpat laoreet tortor. Suspendisse sodales libero velit, sed pulvinar lectus feugiat vel. Sed erat eros, porttitor id enim nec, ornare hendrerit nibh. Phasellus at nisi lectus. Cras semper lobortis condimentum.
    Etiam nunc felis, vehicula vitae tincidunt pellentesque, pretium sit amet dui. Duis aliquet ultrices lacus eget efficitur. Ut imperdiet velit sed enim laoreet, sed semper libero hendrerit. Donec malesuada auctor sollicitudin.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);

Comment: For info, playground of this code copied here: https://jsfiddle.net/xcof19zv/2/

Answer (score 5):

I tried a lot of plugins, most of them don't support all browsers, I prefer [**iScroll**](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?zyslW0N2) and [**nanoScroller**](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/) works for all these browsers :

- IE11 -> IE6
- IE10 - WP8
- IE9 - WP7
- IE Xbox One
- IE Xbox 360
- Google Chrome
- FireFox
- Opera
- Safari

**But** iScroll do not work with touch!

demo **iScroll** : http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll/examples/simple/ 
demo **nanoScroller** : http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

Comment: nano scroller does not support horizontal scroll.

Comment: The repo is archived https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll I would suggest looking for other alternatives

Answer (score 5):

```css
    .className::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }
    
    .className::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

gave me a nice mobile/osx like one.

Comment: A more concise response. IMHO it actually answered the OP's question which was how to style just one div. Nice.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox new version(64) support CSS Scrollbars Module Level 1

```css
.scroller {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-color: rebeccapurple green;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
Veggies es bonus vobis, proinde vos postulo essum magis kohlrabi
welsh onion daikon amaranth tatsoi tomatillo melon azuki bean garlic.
Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette
tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato.
Dandelion cucumber earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini.
</div>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars

[image: Firefox scrollbar]

https://codepen.io/fatihhayri/pen/pqdrbd

Answer (score 3):

Here's a webkit example which works for Chrome and Safari:

**CSS:**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
    width: 40px;
    background-color:#4F4F4F;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment 
{
    height:40px;
    background-image: url(/Images/Scrollbar/decrement.png);
    background-size:39px 30px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement 
{
    height:40px;
    background-image: url(/Images/Scrollbar/increment.png);    
    background-size:39px 30px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is what Google has used in some of its applications for a long time now. See in the code that, if you apply next classes, they somehow hide the scrollbar in Chrome, but it still works.

The classes are `jfk-scrollbar`, `jfk-scrollbar-borderless`, and `jfk-scrollbar-dark`

```css
.testg{ border:1px solid black;  max-height:150px;  overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; width: 250px;}
.content{ height: 700px}

/* The google css code for scrollbars */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 16px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 16px
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    height: 0;
    width: 0
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 0 7px
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
    border-width: 7px 0 0
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 0 7px;
    min-height: 28px;
    padding: 100px 0 0;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    border-width: 7px 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 100px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .37)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-borderless::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-width: 0 1px 0 6px
}
.jfk-scrollbar-borderless::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
    border-width: 6px 0 1px
}
.jfk-scrollbar-borderless::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .035);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-borderless.jfk-scrollbar-dark::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .07);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-borderless::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-width: 0 1px 0 6px
}
.jfk-scrollbar-borderless::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    border-width: 6px 0 1px
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background: transparent
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: solid #fff;
    border-width: 0 0 0 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:horizontal {
    border-width: 3px 0 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 5px
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    border-width: 5px 1px 1px
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: solid #fff;
    border-width: 3px 0 0 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14)
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 16px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 16px
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    height: 0;
    width: 0
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 0 7px
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
    border-width: 7px 0 0
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 0 7px;
    min-height: 28px;
    padding: 100px 0 0;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    border-width: 7px 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 100px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .37)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-dark.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-borderless.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-width: 0 1px 0 6px
}
.jfk-scrollbar-borderless.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
    border-width: 6px 0 1px
}
.jfk-scrollbar-borderless.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .035);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-borderless.jfk-scrollbar-dark.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .07);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)
}
.jfk-scrollbar-borderless.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-width: 0 1px 0 6px
}
.jfk-scrollbar-borderless.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    border-width: 6px 0 1px
}
.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background: transparent
}
body.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: solid #fff;
    border-width: 0 0 0 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
body.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:horizontal {
    border-width: 3px 0 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07)
}
body.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 5px
}
body.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    border-width: 5px 1px 1px
}
body.jfk-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: solid #fff;
    border-width: 3px 0 0 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14)
}
```

```html
<div class="testg">
    <div class="content">
        Look Ma'  my scrollbars doesn't have arrows <br /><br />
        content, content, content <br /> content, content, content <br /> content, content, content s<br />  content, content, content <br/> content, content, content <br/> content, content, content d<br/>  content, content, content <br/> 
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="testg jfk-scrollbar jfk-scrollbar-borderless jfk-scrollbar-dark">
    <div class="content">
        Look Ma'  my scrollbars dissapear in chrome<br /><br />
        content, content, content <br /> content, content, content <br /> content, content, content s<br />  content, content, content <br/> content, content, content <br/> content, content, content d<br/>  content, content, content <br/> 
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/76kcuem0/32/

I just found it useful to remove the arrows from the scrollbars. As of 2015 it's been used in Google Maps when searching for places in the list of results in its material design UI.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way by which you can apply custom scrollbars to custom div elements in your HTML documents. Here is a an example which helps. https://codepen.io/adeelibr/pen/dKqZNb But as a gist of it. You can do something like this.

```
<div class="scrollbar" id="style-1">
  <div class="force-overflow"></div>
</div>
```

CSS file looks like this.

```
.scrollbar
{
  margin-left: 30px;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 65px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.force-overflow
{
  min-height: 450px;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  background-color: #555;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Webkit scrollbar doesnt support on most of the browers.

**Supports on CHROME**

> Here is a demo for webkit scrollbar [Webkit Scrollbar DEMO](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/)
>
> If you are looking for more examples Check this [More Examples](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

---

Another Method is **Jquery Scroll Bar Plugin**

It supports on all browsers and easy to apply

> Download the plugin from [Download Here](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/m-custom-scrollbar-plugin.zip)
>
> How to use and for more options [CHECK THIS](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

[DEMO](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html)

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of JS and CSS scroll's and I found this was very easy to use and tested on IE and Safari and FF and worked fine

AS @thebluefox suggests

Here is how it works

**Add the below script to the**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="facescroll.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){ // on page DOM load
        $('#demo1').alternateScroll();
        $('#demo2').alternateScroll({ 'vertical-bar-class': 'styled-v-bar', 'hide-bars': false });  
    })
</script>
```

And this here in the paragraph where you need to scroll

```
<div id="demo1" style="width:300px; height:250px; padding:8px; resize:both; overflow:scroll">
**Your Paragraph Comes Here**
</div>
```

For more details visit the plugin page

[FaceScroll Custom scrollbar](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/facescroll/index.htm)

hope it help's

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the div as

```
<div class="custom_scroll"> ... </div>
```

Apply CSS Styles as

```
//custom scroll style definitions
.custom_scroll
{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

//custom_scroll scrollbar styling
.custom_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    //background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.custom_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    //background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.custom_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    //background-color: #555;
}
```

Resulting Scroll will appear as

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have skillfully crafted a cross-browser compatible custom scrollbar solution, ensuring a seamless blend of aesthetics and functionality, validated through thorough testing across multiple platforms.
**HTML Code**

```
<div class="scrollbar">
      Dummy Text Lorem ipsum asperiores, dolor magni culpa voluptas maiores? Quidem fuga illum consequuntur maxime eius sed, assumenda
      necessitatibus provident nostrum cupiditate odit animi laboriosam ipsum libero rerum voluptatem repellat dolores
      reprehenderit dolorem. Dolorum iusto nam nisi assumenda nihil harum quis sed veritatis debitis, pariatur provident
      aliquid eius, voluptatem repudiandae? Aperiam repellendus tempora ullam sapiente. Officia, quaerat! Voluptatum,
      fugit?
</div>
```

**Plain CSS Code**

```
.scrollbar {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #a8a8a8 !important;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(83, 83, 83, 0.07);
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

Please also look at the **[demo](https://codepen.io/bllawal/pen/abMxoQM)** it's working alright.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For people still looking for a good solution just I find out this plugin [simplebar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar)

> Custom scrollbars vanilla javascript library with native scroll, done simple, lightweight, easy to use and cross-browser.

In my case, I was looking for reactJS solutions, the author also provides wrappers for react, angular, vue and next [examples](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/tree/master/examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Webkit browsers (such as Chrome, Safari and Opera) supports the non-standard **::-webkit-scrollbar** pseudo element, which allows us to modify the look of the browser's scrollbar.

**Note:** The **::-webkit-scrollbar** is not supported by Firefox or IE and Edge.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 8rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: .8em;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
 
.box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</p>
</div>
```

**Reference:**
[How To Create a Custom Scrollbar](https://parrot-tutorial.com/howto/howto_custom_scrollbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use Only CSS work in Firefox +64

```
.mycoldiv{
    scrollbar-color: white rebeccapurple;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    display: block;
    height:400px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

**More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars**

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `::-wekbit-scrollbar` for all the scrollbars, and you can use:

```
<style>
.mydiv {
height:100px;
overflow:auto;
}
     /* width */
    .mydiv::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 20px;
    }
    
    /* Track */
    .mydiv::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
     
    /* Handle */
    .mydiv::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: red;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    /* Handle on hover */
    .mydiv::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
      background: #b30000; 
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class="mydiv"> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For people using sass here is a mixin with basic functionality (thumb,track color and width). I did not test it extensively so feel free to point any errors.

```css
@mixin element-scrollbar($thumb-color, $background-color: mix($thumb-color, white,  50%), $width: 1rem) {
  // For Webkit
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: $thumb-color;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: $background-color;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: $width;
    height: $width;
  }

  // For Internet Explorer
  & {
    scrollbar-face-color: $thumb-color;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: $thumb-color;
    scrollbar-track-color: $background-color;
  }

  // For Firefox future compatibility
  // This is W3C draft and does not work yet. Use html-firefox-scrollbar mixin instead.
  & {
    scrollbar-color: $thumb-color $background-color;
    scrollbar-width: $width;
  }
}

// For Firefox
@mixin html-firefox-scrollbar($thumb-color, $background-color: mix($thumb-color, white,  50%), $firefox-width: this) {
  // This must be used on html/:root element to take effect
  & {
    scrollbar-color: $thumb-color $background-color;
    scrollbar-width: $firefox-width;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or use somthing like this:

```
var MiniScroll=function(a,b){function e(){c.scrollUpdate()}function f(){var a=new Date,b=Math.abs(a-c.animation.frame),d=c.countScrollHeight();c.animation.frame=a,c.render(b),d.height!=c.controls.height&&(e(),c.controls.height=d.height),requestAnimationFrame(f)}function g(){c.scrollUpdate()}function h(a){var b=c.target.scrollTop,d=Math.abs(a.wheelDeltaY/(10-c.speed));c.target.scrollTop=a.wheelDeltaY>0?b-d:b+d,c.scrollUpdate()}function i(a){if(a.target.classList.contains("scroll"))return a.preventDefault(),!1;var b=c.countScrollHeight();c.target.scrollTop=a.offsetY*b.mul-parseInt(b.height)/2,c.scrollUpdate()}b=b||{};var c=this,d={speed:"speed"in b?b.speed:7};this.target=document.querySelector(a),this.animation={frame:new Date,stack:[]},this.identity="scroll"+parseInt(1e5*Math.random()),this.controls={place:null,scroll:null,height:0},this.speed=d.speed,this.target.style.overflow="hidden",this.draw(),requestAnimationFrame(f),this.target.onscroll=g,this.target.addEventListener("wheel",h),this.controls.place.onclick=i};MiniScroll.prototype.scrollUpdate=function(){this.controls.place.style.height=this.target.offsetHeight+"px";var a=this.countScrollHeight();this.controls.scroll.style.height=a.height,this.controls.scroll.style.top=a.top},MiniScroll.prototype.countScrollHeight=function(){for(var a=this.target.childNodes,b=parseInt(this.target.offsetHeight),c=0,d=0;d<a.length;d++)a[d].id!=this.identity&&(c+=parseInt(a[d].offsetHeight)||0);var e=this.target.offsetHeight*parseFloat(1/(parseFloat(c)/this.target.offsetHeight)),f=this.controls.place.offsetHeight*(this.target.scrollTop/c)+"px";return{mul:c/this.target.offsetHeight,height:e>b?b+"px":e+"px",top:f}},MiniScroll.prototype.draw=function(){var a=document.createElement("div"),b=document.createElement("div");a.className="scroll-place",b.className="scroll",a.appendChild(b),a.id=this.identity,this.controls.place=a,this.controls.scroll=b,this.target.insertBefore(a,this.target.querySelector("*")),this.scrollUpdate()},MiniScroll.prototype.render=function(a){for(var b=0;b<this.animation.stack.length;b++){var c=this.animation.stack[b],d=parseInt(c.target);c.element.style[c.prop]=d+c.points}};
```

And initialize:

```
<body onload="new MiniScroll(this);"></body>
```

And customize:

```
.scroll-place { // ... // }
.scroll { // ... // }
```