# special scroll bar design using css3 or tricks

Tags: css, scrollbar

I want to design a scroll bar using css3 just like for chrome we have css3 code ie.webkit-scrollbar { /* 1 / } webkit-scrollbar-button { / 2 / } webkit-scrollbar-track { / 3 / } webkit-scrollbar-thumb { / 5 / } webkit-scrollbar-corner { / 6 / } webkit-resizer { / 7 */ } Is there any thing such like this for IE & Firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS customized scroll bar in div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know is that no gecko browser has implemented these features. this means it won't work in firefox and netscape. I'm not sure about opera and for IE you can refer to http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/scrollbar-colours.shtml

Comment: does IE10 will support custom scroll css just like chrome supports

Comment: IE supports custom scrollbars since ages ago... refer to the url in my answer for IE