# CSS,HTML or Jquery - Scrollbar style

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

How do I create a scrollbar like this?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-custom-scrollbar-in-div

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use CSS.

http://beautifulpixels.com/goodies/create-custom-webkit-scrollbar/