# Issue with full page horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jscrollpane

**Is any other alternative for full page scroll?**

example of full page scroll

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html

step-1 make window width smaller by clicking Restore down button.

step-2 scroll to right

step-3 now, make window width bigger by clicking Maximize button.

now, page is left aligned

jQuery

```
 $(function()
{
    var win = $(window);

    win.bind(
        'resize',
        function()
        {

                var container = $('#full-page-container');

                container.css(
                    {
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    }
                );

                container.css(
                    {
                        'width': win.width(),
                        'height': win.height()
                    }
                );
                isResizing = false;
                container.jScrollPane(
                    {
                        'showArrows': true
                    }
                );

        }
    ).trigger('resize');


    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');


    if ($('#full-page-container').width() != win.width()) {
        win.trigger('resize');
    }


});
```

CSS

```
html
{
    overflow: auto;
}
#full-page-container
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: can you show your jquery codes?

Comment: @Chanckjh , you can see updated question. check jscrollpane demo link.

Comment: I've just checked in Chrome, and yep, it happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing here is that jScrollPane adds jspPane a left:-***px when you scroll to the right. And never undoes the damage.

If you would add:

`$('#full-page-container .jspPane').css('left', 'auto');`

In your resize, it will work. Although I suggest you report a bug for jScrollPane guys as well.

Comment: Is any other alternative for full page scroll?

Comment: In one project we started using jScrollPane and had a lot of similar problems along the way. So we decided to use it only for small parts, that had to be extra fancy and added a webkit scrollbar style (http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) for everything else. Since our majority of users use chrome/safari it was good enough.

Comment: I list some alternative JavaScript scroll bar solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14150577/1085891