# Custom scroll bar Internet Explorer issue

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a custom scroll bar accomplished by the code [as shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/tKfJs/):

```
::selection {
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 9px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background:#eee;
    border: thin solid lightgray;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background:#999;
    border: thin solid gray;
}
```

It works fine on Chrome, Firefox... but **Internet Explorer** it does not work
What should I add?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS customized scroll bar in div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS specified will only apply a custom scrollbar on a webkit browser such as Chrome and Safari. Internet Explorer only supports a limited amount of scrollbar customisation. See the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and this [IE scrollbar CSS generator](http://www.spectrum-research.com/V2/projects_scrollbar_generator.asp).

Also, Firefox doesn't support custom scrollbars ([bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790)), so I'm not sure how your CSS is working in Firefox - it isn't for me.

If you want, you can use JavaScript-based [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to implement custom scrollbars in all browsers, but be warned, many people hate the user experience on JavaScript scrollbars, myself included.