# customize scroll bar using css

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have done the following to customize my scroll bar

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

the problem is that this works only on chrome and safari. Any idea how to modify it in order to work for IE, opera and Mozila?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946789/custom-scroll-bar-internet-explorer-issue

Answer (score 1):

I think the prefix `-webkit-` consider only scroll bars on safari and chrome. you should add `-moz-`, `-o-` and `-ms-` to complete the code. Hope i helped.