# How to style the ScrollBar using CSS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to style the scroll bar, ex: changing its color.
I use this and it does not works.

CSS:

```
scrollbar-base-color:#369;
scrollbar-3dlight-color:#ffd700; 
scrollbar-arrow-color:#ff0; 
scrollbar-base-color:#ff6347; 
scrollbar-darkshadow-color:#ffa500; 
scrollbar-face-color:#008080; 
scrollbar-highlight-color:#ff69b4; 
scrollbar-shadow-color:#f0f
```

By the ways, I want the code compatible with cross browsers

Could anyone help please?

Comment: These are all non-standard. They _should_ not work.

Comment: The scrollbar is a native GUI widget. Unless you're myspace2, why would you do this to your users?

Comment: [link](http://websitetips.com/articles/css/scrollbars/) I got this from the link.

Comment: _“Scrollbar colors show up in Internet Explorer 5.5+. Other browsers will see the default gray scrollbars.”_

Comment: @xufox Thats like saying "If you want to know how to test blood pressure, go to medical school"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered already multiple times on SO , here are a few links , that should get you sorted :

[Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox).

[Customize scrollbars using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011867/customize-scrollbars-using-css)

[Customize scrollbars using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760830/customize-scroll-bar-using-css)

[How can I create custom scrollbar for Mozilla Firefox ith CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480565/how-can-i-create-custom-scrollbar-for-mozilla-firefox-with-css).

> [this](http://www.noupe.com/development/30-javascriptajax-techniques-for-sliders-scrollers-and-scrollbars.html) should get you started. Long story short, a custom
>   css-styled div is used in conjunction with JavaScript to catch
>   click-and-drag events on the custom div. Wired up to these events are
>   methods that scroll the contents of whatever div the custom-scroller
>   has been attached to.
>
> I'm all about the learning experience -- but after you've learned how
>   it works, I recommend using a library (of which there are many) to do
>   it. It's one of those "don't reinvent" things...

the above is a quote from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945547/how-to-create-a-custom-scrollbar-on-a-div).

but if ur in a hurry and want to skip the learning phase , [heres](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) a plugin thats dead simple to use , and must less hassle then its competition .