# How to remove the arrows in a scroll bar through CSS

Tags: html, css

Generally in a scroll bar there will be up and down arrows at both ends in a vertical scroll bar.

Is there anyway to remove it so that only the scroll bar appears and not the arrows at both ends. Below is my CSS:

```
.scrollbar-vertical
{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 17px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color:#999;
    scrollbar-arrow-color:white;
    scrollbar-base-color:white;
    scrollbar-face-color:#999;
    border-radius:5px 5px; 
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you're trying to obtain a custom scrollbar, that is still able to scroll the page, right? If that is the case, I recommend https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll It's very customizable and works on mobile devices as well.

Comment: Possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div

Comment: You could also try this one: http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/complete_examples.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Assuming that you want to customize the browser scrollbar,

You can do this easily with some nice Jquery Plugins, or you can do the magic with css. But it only works on webkit browsers for now, Here is how

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Else you can use a plugin. (Recommended)

As in an early comment, i suggest you use the niceScroller Plugin. That's nice and easy.

Source : http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Simple Implementation

```
<script> 

     $(document).ready(

      function() { 

        $("html").niceScroll();

      }

    );

</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below style in your css to hide scrollbar arrows,

```
::-moz-scrollbar-button:decrement,
::-moz-scrollbar-button:increment,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:increment {
  width: 0px;
}
```

or

```
::-moz-scrollbar-button, ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in all css states.
The track fills the empty space left behind from the buttons

```
::webkit-scrollbar-button { 
     display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this how I've fixed it :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
   height: 0;
   width: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have skillfully crafted a cross-browser compatible custom scrollbar solution, ensuring a seamless blend of aesthetics and functionality, validated through thorough testing across multiple platforms.
**HTML Code**

```
<div class="scrollbar">
      Dummy Text Lorem ipsum asperiores, dolor magni culpa voluptas maiores? Quidem fuga illum consequuntur maxime eius sed, assumenda
      necessitatibus provident nostrum cupiditate odit animi laboriosam ipsum libero rerum voluptatem repellat dolores
      reprehenderit dolorem. Dolorum iusto nam nisi assumenda nihil harum quis sed veritatis debitis, pariatur provident
      aliquid eius, voluptatem repudiandae? Aperiam repellendus tempora ullam sapiente. Officia, quaerat! Voluptatum,
      fugit?
</div>
```

**Plain CSS Code**

```
.scrollbar {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #a8a8a8 !important;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(83, 83, 83, 0.07);
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

Please also look at the **[demo](https://codepen.io/bllawal/pen/abMxoQM)** it's working alright.
Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

```
visibility: collapse !important;
```

maybe ?

Comment: Dont think so. I fi give that even the actual scroll bar bar does not show up. I just want the up and down arrows not to be shown.

Comment: @ckv Go with the javascript-based solution I recommend in my 1st comment, you'll save yourself a lot of trouble. See Revolt's comment for details why.