# Disable arrow keys scroll in browser without e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove the feature of scrolling in a page with arrows. In all other posts that I have checked they suggested e.preventDefault() function. I tried it but it was also blocking many default features for arrows that are heavily used in my page. I want just to block the scrolling with arrows and not the default behavior of arrows. What solution do you suggest in this case?

Please don't mark as a duplicate since in all the other posts e.preventDefault() was taken as solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent scrolling with arrow keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208021/prevent-scrolling-with-arrow-keys)

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran come on, just read the problem.

Comment: yeah I did. Look into the accepted answer in the link.

Comment: Take a look at this answer:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758578/how-to-remove-the-arrows-in-a-scroll-bar-through-css] Else you can install a plugin named **nicescroll** as mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest playing with `document.activeElement` and `e.preventDefault()` when the active element is an input, textarea and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just added some conditions on it and it worked :)

Comment: You are welcome. And you may accept the answer if it was helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft' || e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```