# Trying to apply a custom scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, interface

I'm trying to apply a similar type of custom scroll bar into my website but I seem to be having some trouble.

[image]

Just want to know if this kind of custom scroll bar is complicated or easy to implement. This is the last obstacle in finishing my design. What are some suggestions or ideas for implementing this design?

Comment: I'm using [**NiceScroll**](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll) plugin and it's really nice. - here you have [some demos](http://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/demo.html)

Comment: Check out this post :) I still have it in my favourites. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of jQuery UI plugin available and you can do this easily. Check it [here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/07/jquery-scrollbar-plugin-examples/) and choose one.

Answer (score 0):

it is pretty easy to implement you `can google for custom scrollbars or you can use` [tinyscrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) or [this](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are many javascript scrollbar scripts. You can try this one: http://www.dyn-web.com/code/scroll/ -> looks like you can easily replicate the scrollbar from your screenshot using this one.

Answer (score -1):

You can try -webkit- scrollbar.Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MohammadHamza/DpjpL/).Here is the code.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 8px; height:8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
background:#fff;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background: rgba(139,233,38,0.8);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: the world does not live with only 1 browser!

Comment: your solution is for all scrolls in the page, I assume that he wants only for that particular `div`,