# How do I style the scrollbar for the Chosen jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery

I have been playing around with the Chosen jquery plugin. I have altered it to a dark style using CSS, but now i want to style the scrollbar so it is not the same default browser scrollbar which is way too light for my webpage. For most of the content on my page I am using NiceScroll plugin, and set the colors to be dark as well. I would really like to use this nicescroll in the Chosen search box as well, but when I try this it renders the searchbox unusable, as it refuses to drop down and search. Is there any plugin i can use to style the scrollbar in Chosen, or should I look for another way to style my search/input boxes all together?

```
$(".chosenbox").niceScroll();
```

using this makes the dropdown list no longer drop down, but it can still scroll through the items in list with the mousewheel.

```
    echo "<div id='dark-select' class='box'>";
    echo "<select name='band' class='chosenbox ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-corner-right ui-state-default'>";
    echo "<option name='select' value='' disabled selected>Search by Band</option>";

while ( $therow = mysql_fetch_array($results) )
{
    $theband = $therow["band"];
    echo("<option name='");
    echo($theband);
    echo("' value='");
    echo($theband);
    echo("'");
    if ($theband == $band)
        echo(" selected");
    echo(">");
    echo($theband);
    echo("</option>");
}       
echo("</select>");
echo("</div><div class='box' width='100'>&nbsp;</div>");
```

this code creates the scrollbar, but incorrectly as it puts the scrollbar way over to the left, not inside the results where it should be.

```
$(".chosen-results").niceScroll();
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS customized scroll bar in div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div)

Comment: no this is not duplicate, since i am not trying style a div. or am I? looks like no one is familiar with Chosen, I guess I should try something more customizeable.