# CSS3 column property border bug with horizontal scroll

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

I want to use  CSS3 column border. But is not working with horizontal (overflow-x) scrolling. It self as if sticky thinks.

```
column-rule: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
-moz-column-rule: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
-webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
```

sample:
http://codepen.io/mrsarac/pen/KokFG

Comment: It's because the horizontal scroll is not a column. [**This SO post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div) may be helpful as well

Comment: Yep! Thank you for your advice. I saw the problem. 
I moved overflow-x property outer div than fixed problem.