# How to manage width of scroll in ScrollPanel in GWT UIBinder?

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

I am new to GWT(UIBinder). I wanted to apply CSS to `Scroll` (to change width, color)in `ScrollPanel` in `UIBinder`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div

Comment: css are not same for all browsers but this can help http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/