# Styling the scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have implemented a section with scroll bar which will display the description. its working fine now. but its having the default style now. i want to custom style the scroll bar so that it will look good.

HTML CODE

```
      <div class="desc" style="width:100px; height:300px; overflow: auto; background:#CCC;" >
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem           Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,           when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a           type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap           into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was           popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing           Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing           software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9251354/968301

Comment: Thank you. i tried it and it looks good now. but unfortunately its taking the native scroll bar style in firefox :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slim scroll plugin for this http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll.

Answer (score 0):

CSS scrollbar properties are available to customize it. E.g.:

```
scrollbar-3dlight-color
scrollbar-arrow-color
scrollbar-base-color
scrollbar-darkshadow-color
scrollbar-face-color
scrollbar-highlight-color
```

Detailed answers is available at:
[CSS customized scroll bar in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div)