# How do you remove the boxed that contains the scrollbar

Tags: css

What CSS do you use to remove the box that contains scrollbar, yet leave scrollbar visible?

(Current scrollbar)
[image: I want to remove the box that contains the scrollbar, yet leave scrollbar visible]

(need to look like this one)
[image: This is what I want it to look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with CSS...You will have to use custom js plugin to achieve this.

One that looks like what you shownin the image is called [slimScroll](http://plugins.jquery.com/slimScroll/)

**[DEMO](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/)**

Comment: OK thanks! I will use this!

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the box of the browser's default scrollbar. I think the only way to achieve this is by using a custom scrollbar. Read this answer of how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150577/1119533

Answer (score 0):

I found this example without the use of JS plugin http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/

```
/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}



/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,1); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(200,200,200,0.4); 
}
```

Comment: Safari and Chrome solution only...this won't work natively in Firefox, Opera or IE