# how can I get the equivalent regardin web-kit and moz?

Tags: css

I want to have exactly the same for all browsers, in Chrome my code is working properly, but not in the other Browsers

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: rgba(55, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: get-space(x-small) - 1;
  height: 493.23828647925px;
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 0;
  width: 3px;
  z-index: 99;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: darken(get-color(nieve), 20%);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div