# non-jumpy custom scrollbar without JS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a bit frustrated, it seems that i can't find any custom scrollbar lib that will be as smooth as native scrollbar (on mouse wheel scroll) without faking scroll animation by heavy js, i.e that will simply hide native scrollbar and show custom on it's place.

Looks like all of the "simple" scrollbars just listens for wheel event and then jumps by some step, see http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/

I suppose this was fine some years ago when native scrollbars was "jumpy" also, but now Chrome's scroll is smooth.
This one http://noeldelgado.github.io/gemini-scrollbar/ may look like something i'm looking for, but sadly seems to have some issues oversizing or cutting out content.

Any ideas of good solutions, kind sirs?

Comment: While I do know that in chrome and other webkit browsers you can style the native scrollbar. Can't seem to find any compatibility charts for it though. If its standard across the major browsers now then it would work for you https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: @kurt It would be wonderfull if there will be a cross-browser pure css hooks to style scrollbar, but as per this qustion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div and a little research it seems that currently it's pretty ill-supported