# Scroll bar formatting in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, formatting, scrollbar

Source: http://www.salefee.com/

There is an issue with the scroll bar on http://www.salefee.com/. I have tried to increase its width using inspect element option in chrome. But I am not able to find the same code in index.html(The code for scroll bar which is showing in inspect element option is not there in html file). I have tried to add scroll bar functionality by adding codes for it in html file but the changes are not reflecting on the website. Can you please help me with this scroll bar issue. I want to increase the width of scroll bar.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS customized scroll bar in div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrollbar width is set via .niceScroll() plugin inside your main.js file.
Change the **cursorwidth** parameter to desired value.
[Plugin's documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll#configuration-parameters)

```
$("html").niceScroll({
    cursorwidth: "5px"
})
```

Comment: Thanks..It worked..Do you know how to change the color of scrollbar because by default it is coming black with a white border which is not looking good.

Comment: Check the documetation link above :) It has full description of plugin's options. `cursorcolor: "#424242", // change cursor color in hex` , `cursorborder: "1px solid #fff", // css definition for cursor border`

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that your code is generating on run-time that's why you can't see in your code.  can you paste your code here ?