# Css background color for scroll area

Tags: css, scroll, background

Is there a way to set color for scroll area? (marked with red)
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS customized scroll bar in div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: red;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: darkgrey;
}
```

Only problem is that isnt supported on all browsers.