# setting scroll-bar style(color)

Tags: css, scrollbar

I only want to replace the color of scroll bar,is that possible?I saw all of this(https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) settings but using them, I couldn't find a way to just change color,I needed to set a scrollbar width to see any changes and then the whole website is moved to left by a scrollbar width.

[image]

Comment: ::-webkit-scrollbar { background-color: red;} don't do the thing?

Comment: it won't,only this white part will be red,I want to change only the color of the thing that moves up and down on scroll,without whole website being moved to left as shown on the picture,that picture shows scrollbar with my settings ,but it looks awfully

Comment: oh okay! I don't know a solution for that. but look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div/14150577#14150577