# Is it possible to move a scrollbar using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to move a scrollbar for example, 5px to the right, only using CSS?

Comment: Can you provide some code please ? What did you tried so far ?

Comment: I don't think so. You may want to make a custom scrollbar using jQuery.

Comment: @Magicprog.fr - Lol. That's what **he's** asking for.

Comment: Take a look of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div

Comment: Thanks @JoseAPL, but that question is what made me curious

Comment: @McMuffin that's about all you can do with custom scrollbars, if you want to move it 5px to the right, why not just add 5px right padding on the container?