# Cross browser - Mobile compatible custom Scroll Bar

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, infinite-scroll

As of 2017, is there a way to implement a cross-browser and mobile inclusive custom scrollbar, that supports events for an infinite-scroll (in case of a plugin)?

This question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div), however, this was 5 years ago with the accepted answer last updated on 2014, so I'm hoping for an up-to date answer to this subject.

Some things i have tried:

- [Custom Css](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) (not compatible with all browsers, i'm testing for IE10+ and other modern browsers)
- Most starred git project [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) (Scrollbar won´t be displayed on mobile)
- [Sly](http://darsa.in/sly/#!examples) (2.7k stars on github) - (seems good, not tested for mobile though
- [jquery.nicescroll](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll) - seems like it's not supported anymore

Answer (score 0):

I use Custom Content Scroller aka mCustomScrollbar

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

I tested on mobile and many browsers and work perfectly... btw CSS is not implemented on all browsers yet... I think that CSS is not good choice to change scrollbar appearance at this moment...

Answer (score 0):

What can you do is check some repositories, drill dip in code and decide if you want to rewrite it in your own manner or just reuse it as is.

Below some links to github scrollers maybe first on is mostly suit.

[simplebar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar)

[jquery custom scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Maybe if you will provide more details with live example and expected devices, you will get more answers.