# Create custom scrollbar for admin side menus and DIVs using only pure CSS

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

***CSS***

```
.menuScroll{overflow:auto; height:50%; cursor:pointer;}
.menuScroll::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 12px;}
.menuScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgb(161,136,127);border-radius: 10px;}
.menuScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {border-radius: 10px;-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgb(176,190,197);}
```

***HTML***

```
<ul class="sub-menu menuScroll">
```

[View Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGb5T.png)

Comment: Maybe [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900473/how-to-get-fat-scroll-bar-on-div-using-css) from earlier today can help you?

Comment: Try this https://scotch.io/tutorials/customize-the-browsers-scrollbar-with-css

Comment: Reference link https://codepen.io/devstreak/pen/dMYgeO

Comment: For IE 11
--- menuScroll1 {height: 50%;margin-left: 40px;overflow-y: scroll;}