# Alternative for -webkit-scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking for an alternative for -webkit-scrollbar pseudo class.
As its browser dependent(Chrome and Safari). Is there a css alternative or JS code for the same?

```
-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
```

I need to change this.

Comment: Did you check that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150577/5860648