# The ::-webkit-scrollbar is not working for IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scroll, webkit

I used `::-webkit-scrollbar` CSS selector to reduce the width of the horizontal scroll bar as follow;

```css
    ::-webkit-scrollbar
    {
        width: 2px;
        height: 2px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb 
    {
        background-color:black;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Responsive Table</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
  <body>
      <table class="table table-responsive" style="font-size:45px">
        <caption>This is a table</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>GPA</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>GPA</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>GPA</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>GPA</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>GPA</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>GPA</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Its working fine with chrome but its not working for IE. I tried using `ms` along with `webkit` but still no improvement!

Answer (score 4):

There is [no support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar#Browser_compatibility) in IE/Edge.

[image]

Comment: Then what i can do to reduce the width of scroll bar. So that it works in all browsers?.

Comment: @HinaAhmad [Have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div/14150577#14150577)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no native support, but you could try a custom js or jquery plugin?. Here are a few: [jQuery Scrollbar](http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/), [perfect-scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.com/perfect-scrollbar/), [slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/) or [NiceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/).