# Custom scrollbar cross-browser support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

[image]
I am trying to create custom scrollbar in css, but It's not cross-browser, I wanna make it cross-browser with javascript. Scrollbar is not in body tag. Scrollbar is in card box (categories). **Here is the screenshot:**
[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9kBq.png)
**Here is my html code:**

```
<section class="quickSearch">
    <div class="quickSearchWrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="quickSearch-header">
                <div class="fw-5">Quick Search</div>
                <a href="#">View All</a>
            </div>
            <div class="quickSearch-body">
                <div class="quickSearch-categories"> // Here is am placing overflow scrollbar 'x axis'
                    <div class="quickSearch-category">
                        <a href="#" class="btn rounded quickSearch-category--name">Creative</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quickSearch-category">
                        <a href="#" class="btn rounded quickSearch-category--name">Landing Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quickSearch-category">
                        <a href="#" class="btn rounded quickSearch-category--name">eCommerce</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quickSearch-category">
                        <a href="#" class="btn rounded quickSearch-category--name">Education</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quickSearch-category">
                        <a href="#" class="btn rounded quickSearch-category--name">Real Estate</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quickSearch-category">
                        <a href="#" class="btn rounded quickSearch-category--name">Corporate</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quickSearch-category">
                        <a href="#" class="btn rounded quickSearch-category--name">Agency</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quickSearch-category">
                        <a href="#" class="btn rounded quickSearch-category--name">Portfolio</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quickSearch-category">
                        <a href="#" class="btn rounded quickSearch-category--name">Restaurants</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quickSearch-category">
                        <a href="#" class="btn rounded quickSearch-category--name">Jewellery</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Css Code:**

```
.quickSearchWrapper{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.quickSearchWrapper .quickSearch-body .quickSearch-categories{
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
}
.quickSearch-categories::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px; 
    height: 7px;
}
.quickSearch-categories::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #1e202a;
    outline: 1px solid #1e202a;
}
.quickSearch-categories::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.quickSearch-categories::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

I've tried this, but it's not cross-browser. Can someone please tell me, how can i make it support to all browsers? Js or anything? Please help me

Comment: which all browsers don't support this please list them too. I think you have to write separate code for browsers like ie to make the scrollbar elegant.

Comment: Try as mentioned in this link because webkit is suppported by most of browsers and you have write separate code for the rest. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150577/12147721

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to **use javascript** for scrollbars since they are not fully supported by all browsers. those libraries are examples to use:

- **[Simple-scrollbar](https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar)**
- **[SimpleBar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar)**

The following example uses **simpleBar**. see documentation above for options.

```js
new SimpleBar(document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300p;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.text {
text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.css" />
<div id="container">
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p><p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

  
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.min.js"></script>
```

However standards have come with New properties but they are supported only for **firefox**.

**Can I Use** is a website to check support of a property [check here](https://caniuse.com/)

### [scrollbar-width](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar-width/)

```
    scrollbar-width: auto | thin | none | <length>;
```

> **`scrollbar-width` accepts the following values:**
>
> - `auto` is the default value and will render the standard scrollbars for the user agent.
> - `thin` will tell the user agent to use thinner scrollbars, when applicable.
> - `none` will hide the scrollbar completely, without affecting the element's scrollability.
> - `<length>` is being debated, but (if added) would be a maximum width of the scrollbar.

---

### [scrollbar-color](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar-color/)

```
    scrollbar-color: auto | dark | light | <color>;
```

> **`scrollbar-color` accepts the following values:**
>
> - `auto` is the default value and will render the standard scrollbar
>     colors for the user agent.
> - `dark` will tell the user agent to use darker
>     scrollbars to match the current color scheme.
> - `light` will tell the user
>     agent to use lighter scrollbars to match the current color scheme.
> - `<color>` specifies two colors to be used for the scrollbar. The first
>     color is for the "thumb" or the moveable part of the scrollbar which
>     appears on top. The second color is for the "track" or the fixed
>     portion of the scrollbar.

---

So use combinantion of `::-webkit-scrollbar` prefixes for chrome and supported properties listed above for firefox to customize, otherwise it is better to use `js` to assure that your styles are working cross-browser.

Comment: don't wanna use library but for firefox it worked "scrollbar-width: thin". Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you have to add different styles for different browsers. There is no one simple styling for all browsers

For Chrome & Safari:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px; 
  height: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #1e202a;
  outline: 1px solid #1e202a;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

For Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .scroller {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: #1e202a;
  }
}
```

One more thing. CSS property

```
 box-shadow
```

can be used without -webkit- prefix.
To be sure if CSS property needs prefix always check [this](https://caniuse.com)
link

Comment: scrollbar-color requires 2 valid colors, so like scrollbar-color: rebeccapurple green;

Answer (score 0):

Can you please Try this one CSS

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

Comment: this is only for chrome, not cross browser.