# Safari scrollbars custom color and size

Tags: css, ios, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

I want to CSS style my scrollbars in Safari (particularly iPhone).
I guess it's doable in FF (div 2) and Chrome (div 3) but in Safari I can't see any scrollbars.

Divs have `overflow-x: scroll`.

Div 2 has FF specific properties (`scrollbar-width` and `scrollbar-color`)

Div 3 has Chrome specific pseudo classes (`::-webkit-scrollbar` ...)

Here is the example (you can open it in various browsers to get the picture):

https://codepen.io/dalibor123/pen/bGoNYLQ

I was asked if this answers my question, but it doesn't: [CSS customized scroll bar in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div)
because it only deals with Safari on Mac, but I was asking preferably for mobile Safari - iPhone etc

Please open my example with iPhone Safari

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS customized scroll bar in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div)

Comment: No, I need this to work in mobile Safari (iPhone), and that is for webkit for Mac (My example runs well in Mac, but not iPhone)