# How to make a scrollbar be transparent and on top of the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a div with a list of text and a button that adds more lines of text. Once the lines of text reach the bottom of the screen the scrollbar appears. I would like the scrollbar the appear transparent and on top of the div rather than fully opaque and next to the div how it is currently. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If it's transparent then why do you care where it is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS customized scroll bar in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div)

Comment: The scrollbar is currently not transparent and I'd like for it to be on top of the div because there is another div directly next to it that is being moved over when the scrollbar is created.

Comment: That link is a bit helpful for making it transparent, but it doesn't explain how to display it on top of the div.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `overflow:overlay;` to display scrollbar over content and `background-color` on the thumb and track to make them 25% opaque. Please see snippet below :

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  overflow:overlay; 
}
/* ===== Scrollbar CSS ===== */
  /* Firefox */
  * {
    scrollbar-width: auto;
    scrollbar-color: #00000025 #ffffff25;
  }

  /* Chrome, Edge, and Safari */
  *::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
  }

  *::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #ffffff25;
  }

  *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #00000025;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px none #00000025;
  }
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum luctus scelerisque facilisis. Etiam vestibulum neque at ornare lacinia. Phasellus malesuada massa vel dapibus volutpat. Donec elit metus, mollis id egestas vel, mattis et felis. Duis rutrum diam eu lacus molestie mollis. Phasellus interdum imperdiet vehicula. Morbi eget ex massa.

Curabitur interdum semper mauris non efficitur. Ut eros ipsum, blandit sit amet hendrerit sed, tincidunt nec est. Duis finibus posuere orci sit amet semper. Ut quis ligula nec purus elementum accumsan quis id felis. Sed eget imperdiet dui. Suspendisse faucibus porttitor massa. Proin auctor, libero ut pharetra ullamcorper, arcu enim lobortis tellus, in mollis mi turpis vitae nibh. Pellentesque eget neque pharetra, ornare diam quis, vehicula risus. Phasellus pellentesque facilisis enim, vitae elementum augue. Phasellus ac vulputate nunc. Morbi non ante gravida, mattis nisi eu, ullamcorper sem. Nullam egestas ligula ut lectus dapibus vehicula. In in erat viverra, sagittis odio a, venenatis erat. Nunc ut nunc scelerisque, egestas sapien sed, venenatis lorem. Vivamus fringilla nunc leo, in dictum tortor vehicula vitae.

Donec eleifend est in felis molestie convallis. Etiam dolor ligula, lobortis eu molestie feugiat, aliquam eget ligula. Quisque tempor ornare enim, sed varius mi vestibulum sit amet. In at vestibulum ligula. Vivamus pretium non purus vel scelerisque. Pellentesque a mauris sit amet orci lobortis pellentesque. In purus nulla, maximus non sapien vitae, rhoncus tristique arcu. In placerat dui vel iaculis commodo. Nullam malesuada suscipit nulla, at scelerisque tortor vulputate at. In a diam at libero cursus bibendum in vitae libero. In tortor magna, ornare nec massa vitae, sagittis tincidunt turpis.

Proin malesuada in lectus vitae suscipit. Sed nibh risus, accumsan vel enim vel, mattis porta augue. Aliquam et lacinia neque. Etiam pellentesque tempor augue eget ullamcorper. Aenean dictum efficitur dolor sed ultrices. Donec vitae euismod odio. Nam quis posuere ante. Fusce quis sagittis nulla, sit amet gravida urna. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus id auctor mi. Curabitur pellentesque risus et tortor viverra, vitae pretium ex fringilla. Mauris efficitur maximus lorem vitae hendrerit. Cras efficitur sollicitudin sapien sed dignissim. Duis fermentum imperdiet tincidunt. Praesent augue justo, elementum eu pharetra in, iaculis quis ipsum. Donec sit amet varius arcu, in dictum risus.

Ut ex urna, scelerisque quis augue a, viverra bibendum ligula. Aliquam iaculis dolor quis dolor finibus consectetur. Integer vehicula, turpis sed sollicitudin cursus, est justo posuere elit, non facilisis massa nulla id ligula. Duis tempus, sem vel congue scelerisque, augue mauris efficitur tortor, nec commodo magna sapien et eros. Donec ultrices dui mi, ut malesuada odio ornare a. Duis auctor, ex eu ultricies semper, leo diam consequat turpis, eu ornare felis velit rhoncus quam. Vestibulum lacinia ipsum nec ipsum laoreet faucibus. Mauris sed eros sem. Morbi a tellus quam. Nulla porttitor scelerisque massa eu efficitur. In metus libero, viverra fermentum accumsan et, tristique a ipsum. Proin lacinia tortor leo, facilisis volutpat ante elementum vel. Pellentesque sed ipsum ut sem lobortis mollis sed sit amet dolor. Pellentesque vulputate, justo id eleifend congue, felis enim consectetur nibh, id malesuada ipsum enim nec lectus.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to give that a try!

Comment: @TinyManager tell me if that works for you ;) Please upvote if that was useful 