# need to make scroller black

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, scroller

Need to make scroller black. [Here is my example](https://jsfiddle.net/CoolBuys1290/nxuzavo3/1)

Right now scroller is white.

```js
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script');
  ga.type = 'text/javascript';
  ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

```css
[data-scroller="true"] {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scroller-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}

.scroller-scrollbar.vertical {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

.scroller-scrollbar.vertical.scroller-inverse {
  left: 0;
  right: inherit;
}

.scroller-scrollbar.horizontal {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.scroller-scrollbar.horizontal.scroller-inverse {
  top: 0;
  bottom: inherit;
}

.scroller-scrollbar.scroller-active {
  display: block;
}

.scroller-scrollbar {
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.32;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Fxp Jquery Scroller Basic Example</title>
  <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="scroller.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      background: #fafafa;
    }
    
    .container {
      margin: 150px auto;
      max-width: 960px;
    }
    
    .content {
      background: #eee;
      height: 200px;
      width: 300px;
      border-radius: 3px solid #222;
    }
    
    p {
      padding: 2rem 1rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="jquery-script-menu">
    <div class="jquery-script-center">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/custom-fxp-scroller.html">Download This Plugin</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/">Back To jQueryScript.Net</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="carbon-block"></div>
      <div class="jquery-script-ads">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          <!--
          google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2783044520727903";
          /* jQuery_demo */
          google_ad_slot = "2780937993";
          google_ad_width = 728;
          google_ad_height = 90;
          //-->
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
        </script>
      </div>
      <div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="content container" data-scroller="true" data-prevent-mouse-scroll="true" style="overflow-y: scroll; border-radius: 25px;" rows="10" cols="10">
"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
</textarea>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="scroller.js" async="async"></script>
  <script>
    try {
      fetch(new Request("https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js", {
        method: 'HEAD',
        mode: 'no-cors'
      })).then(function(response) {
        return true;
      }).catch(function(e) {
        var carbonScript = document.createElement("script");
        carbonScript.src = "//cdn.carbonads.com/carbon.js?serve=CK7DKKQU&placement=wwwjqueryscriptnet";
        carbonScript.id = "_carbonads_js";
        document.getElementById("carbon-block").appendChild(carbonScript);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script');
      ga.type = 'text/javascript';
      ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no cross-browser solution for this because...reasons? [CSS customized scroll bar in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div) Also if you like reading here's the W3 draft but it doesn't look like it's been updated since last December https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1/#scrollbar-width

Answer (score 0):

maybe it can help you

```css
[data-scroller="true"] {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.scroller-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}
.scroller-scrollbar.vertical {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.scroller-scrollbar.vertical.scroller-inverse {
  left: 0;
  right: inherit;
}
.scroller-scrollbar.horizontal {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
.scroller-scrollbar.horizontal.scroller-inverse {
  top: 0;
  bottom: inherit;
}
.scroller-scrollbar.scroller-active {
  display: block;
}
.scroller-scrollbar {
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.32;
}


textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: black }

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: yellow }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Fxp Jquery Scroller Basic Example</title>
    <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="scroller.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
background: #fafafa;
        }
.container { margin: 150px auto; max-width: 960px; }
        .content {
            background: #eee;
            height: 200px;
            width: 300px;
            border-radius: 3px solid #222;
        }
        p { padding: 2rem 1rem; }
    </style>
</head>

<body><div id="jquery-script-menu">
<div class="jquery-script-center">
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/custom-fxp-scroller.html">Download This Plugin</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/">Back To jQueryScript.Net</a></li>
</ul><div id="carbon-block"></div>
<div class="jquery-script-ads"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2783044520727903";
/* jQuery_demo */
google_ad_slot = "2780937993";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>
<div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<textarea class="content container" data-scroller="true" data-prevent-mouse-scroll="true" style="overflow-y: scroll; border-radius: 25px;" rows="10" cols="10">
"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
</textarea>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="scroller.js" async="async"></script>
<script>
try {
  fetch(new Request("https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js", { method: 'HEAD', mode: 'no-cors' })).then(function(response) {
    return true;
  }).catch(function(e) {
    var carbonScript = document.createElement("script");
    carbonScript.src = "//cdn.carbonads.com/carbon.js?serve=CK7DKKQU&placement=wwwjqueryscriptnet";
    carbonScript.id = "_carbonads_js";
    document.getElementById("carbon-block").appendChild(carbonScript);
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Still no scrollbar.

Comment: did you mean horizontal scroll?

Comment: I'd like a vertical scrollbar that's white and a scroller that's black and rounded like the one in your snippet. Also your example doesn't work on ipad, but that's ok.