# customize vertical and horizonal scrollbar differently using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add two different styles for horizontal an vertical scrollbars.

I want both horizontal and vertical scrolls in my document but with different thicknesses. I want to hide the vertical scrollbar but keep it scrollable.

How do I achieve that?

```html
<div class="scroll-container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: scroll;">
     <div style="width:300px; height:300px;">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Let me google this for you https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS customized scroll bar in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div)

Comment: This is not a site to ask people to write code for you. [tour] [ask] [Help] Inform yourself.

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I wanted to have both horizontal and vertical scrolls in my document but I wanted to have different thicknesses for them. To be specific, I wanted to hide vertical scrollbar but keep it scrollable.
Turns out, if you set **width**, it will change the thickness of vertical scroll and if you set **height**, it'll change the thickness of horizontal scroll.

```css
.scroll-container{
  background: grey;
}
.scroll-container::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 5px; /*sets the thickness of vertical scroll  */
  height: 8px; /*sets the thickness of horizontal scroll */
}
.scroll-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.scroll-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container" style="width: 200px; height: 180px; overflow: scroll;">
  <div style="width:300px; height:300px;">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited to move the start of your original self-answer post into the question post because it is part of the question so that is where it belongs. You should not have rolled back my edit. [ask] [answer] [Help] PS A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly" or "it is false that". When it introduces one it is unnecessary & misleading.

Answer (score 2):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: blue;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal{
        background: red;
        border-radius: 1px;
 }
```

You can do something like this to style both of them